# Why java isn't in the JRE part in the diagram

Tags: java

In the Java Conceptual Diagram, why **java** (the first blue box) isn't in the JRE part?

As I understand the diagram:

JDK = Java Language + Tools & Tool APIs (**java**, javac, etc) + JRE

But it's like **java** only comes with the JDK and not with the JRE.
So could we put this **java** in the JRE part?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/

[image: Oracle Java Conceptual Diagram]

Comment: if you look at again, it is mentioned already

Comment: Removed the Oracle tag as this is not related to Oracle Databases.

Comment: I still don't see the "java" in the JRE part. It is not mentioned, so maybe there is something I don't understand in the diagram. And that's why I'm asking the question, to understand.

Comment: On the left, the bracket within the JDK bracket. Everything under the blue boxes (Tools and Tool APIs) is JRE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good point. The `java` executable comes under "Deployment". If you click on the Deployment link, you get https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/index.html which includes the following sentence:

> Users can start the application from the command line using the Java launcher, or by double-clicking the JAR file for the application.

The Java Launcher is the `java` executable you are referring to. So `java` is referred to indirectly under the JRE umbrella. The diagram really should have had three columns on the line that includes "Java Web Start" and "Applet/Java Plugin". It should also have a box on that line labelled "Java Application Launcher". (Also, the "Applet/Java Plugin" should be marked as deprecated.)